# Send email using classic ASP to exchange server with trusted connections

Tags: asp-classic, exchange-server

I have an existing classic ASP application that uses CDO to send a mail through SMTP.  As far as I know this has always worked with exchange servers.  A customer now is telling me they have trusted connections with their exchange server and no other application they have needs to sign in with username/password through SMTP, aka my method is archaic and they want me to use trusted connections.

How would you send mail using CDO with classic ASP to an exchange server with trusted connections?

Comment: do you have to use CDO? or could you use another technology?

Comment: could you tell which version of the exchange server is used? because from Exchange 2010 on CDO is a discontinued feature... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998911.aspx#Disc2003to2010

Comment: i was using CDO so it works with all forms of SMTP servers. is there a better more universal way so the user can have any mail system they want?